# LimeSDR installation problems

Tags: gnuradio

I installed the necessary for the limeSDR USB.

The software examples do not find the board connected to the USB.
The test utility and the Suite are able to connect to the board.
Is there anybody to help me?

I installed the dependancy as explained.
The examples are generated. I open the visual studio, launch the project and no board is found.

I would like to run the example.

Comment: which project? what does this have to do with GNU Radio?

Comment: Thank You for coming here. I struggled a couple of weeks. I have the LimeSDR usb. I followed the instructions but the example did not connect to the device. I ended in debugging the software inside the source code. I landed in the lack of the source code for the USB connectivity. I added to the project manually and it worked. Later I was able to figure out the settings that was incorrect in the CMake. It was a hard time. But now it is over

Comment: which instructions? Which software? Nobody can read your mind. But if you have solved the issue, I think it would be fair to close/delete your question now, right?

Comment: I think it is closed. Thank the community for giving help.
The problem was the procedure for the installation requires an attention and competence during the preparation of the CMAKE. I placed an inappropriate value wihich excluded from the build the connection with the windows env.
I ended in digging the code for discovering it was not supporting the connection on windows
Thank You

Comment: Please apply my previous comment, then.